# can't support concated int and string directly in c++?

Tags: c++

```
int x=10;
string str;
str+=x;
cout<<"hello"<<str<<endl;
```

why print hello only, not hello10?

can't concat int and string in c++?

Comment: @VusP yes it is, just not for ints.\

Comment: yes.as you demonstrated in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ does not have a true character type; in C++, characters are
an integral type, and when you add a number to a string, it is
considered a character code.  On most systems, `10` corresponds
to the character code for a new line, so in your example, `str
+= x;` appends a new line character to `str`.  (Treating any
arithmetic type as a char is probably not a good idea, but this
has been the case since the earliest days of C, and changing
anything here now is out of the question, given the amount of
code it would break.  On the other hand, using `+` or `+=` to
format non-string types is definitely a bad idea.)

If you need to format non-string data as a string, use
`std::ostringstream`.  This will also allow you to specify *how*
you want things formatted.  (There are many ways to represent
the numeric value `10` as a string.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/?kw=stringstream) for this kind of requirement.

```
int x=10;
stringstream ss;//create a stringstream
ss << x;//add number to the stream
string str=ss.str();
cout<<"hello"<<str<<endl;//Will print hello10
return 0;
```

Comment: Beat me by 4 seconds :) But please use http://en.cppreference.com/ when you give references, http://www.cplusplus.com/ contains some questionable examples.

Comment: Of course, if you're outputting to a stream, you don't need `std::ostringstream`; you can just output the `int`.  (And you shouldn't use `stringstream`, but `std::ostringstream`.)

Answer (score 2):

You first need to convert `x` to a `std::string`:

```
 string str = std::to_string(x) /* + "" */;
```

Comment: which lib/h contain std::to_string()?

Comment: @jiafu `<string>`, in C++11.

Comment: is need to enable c++11 in make? how to enable it ?